# Will thousands of changefeed listeners kill the performance?

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm building an application where every user will be notified when anything happens to nearby (location) users.
Im thinking about something like the following:
Whenever a user logs in, the server queries the db about changes for any nearby user, and notifies the logged in user of any changes via a websocket.

This would mean a lot of changefeedes open to the database (at least one per user). How will that effect performance? Say I have 1000 users, will those changefeed listeners even be possible to handle?
And can I cancel the changefeed once the user logs out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RethinkDB should be able to handle 1000 changefeeds just fine unless it's on extremely bad hardware.  You can close a changefeed at any time (most drivers literally call the method `close`).